# Android: Google OAuth2 Scopes Format

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

Tutorials and documentation for Google OAuth2 login with Android are very inconsistent about the format and style of the scopes used with GoogleAuthUtil.getToken. Do you include scopes as URLs or words, do you include the client id or not, and do you use the Android app, the Service account, or web app id? I'm trying it like this now:

```
String mScope="oauth2:server:client_id:XXXXXXXXXX:api_scope:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login"
```

But it throws a GoogleAuthException: Unknown error. If we don't include the client id we get back an access token, but then trying to authenticate with our backend Django web app, we get a 403: Forbidden error.

Answer (score 1):

There's an example at https://github.com/googledrive/crossclientoauth2-android:

```
final private String CLIENT_ID = "abc123.apps.googleusercontent.com";
final private List<String> SCOPES = Arrays.asList(new String[]{
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"
});

String scope = String.format("oauth2:server:client_id:%s:api_scope:%s", CLIENT_ID, TextUtils.join(" ", SCOPES));
```